# Terraform get public key from Asymmetric KMS Keypair

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-kms, terraform-aws-modules

You can create Asymmetric key pairs (Encrypt/Decrypt) in AWS KMS. Current AWS CLI allow for public key to be accessed (https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/kms/get-public-key.html)

I am not able to see this being available in Terraform's KMS resource. Am I missing something or this is just not available in latest release yet,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not supported in terrorism for now. There are some github issues related to this already, such as [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/11053).

Comment: Thank you. I read that bug just wasn'y sure if I missed something or not. Hopefully it'll get included soon

Comment: terrorism.. I got a good laugh